# Relación de dependencia en JAVA

Tags: java, poo, clase, objeto

Leyendo un libro en java me encontré con las relaciones de dependencias entre clases y dice lo siguiente:

> La relación de dependencia es una relación de utilización, donde el cambio en el estado de un objeto (el independiente) afecta el estado del otro (el dependiente), pero no a la inversa. Esta relación aparece en la practica cuando una clase se relaciona con otra a través de los mensajes que le envía (métodos que invoca). Es decir, que se pasa un ejemplar de la clase independiente como uno de los parámetros del método invocado (el de la clase dependiente).

Después de leer esto trate de implementar un programa que usara lo de la relación de dependencia. Pero tengo serias dudas de que este bien, ya que por lo que entendí, la clase dependiente cambia de estado con solo cambiar el estado del objeto que se le paso por parámetro y no es necesario volver a llamar al método en donde se utiliza como parámetro el objeto de la clase independiente.

En caso de que este malo el ejercicio, podrían compartir un ejemplo donde se use relación de dependencia, por favor.

A continuación les dejo el código:

Clase principal:

```
package relacionDeDependencia;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Distancia distancia=new Distancia(1,4);
     Punto punto=new Punto(0,0);
     
     for(int i=1;i<11;i++) {
         distancia.calcDistancia(punto);
         distancia.mostrar();
         punto.setPunto(2*i,i);
     }
   }

}
```

Clase distancia:

```
  package relacionDeDependencia;

  public class Distancia {
    public double distancia;
    private Punto puntoInicial;
  
    public Distancia(int x, int y) {
       puntoInicial=new Punto(x,y);
    }
        
    public void calcDistancia(Punto puntoFinal) {
       distancia=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(puntoFinal.x-puntoInicial.x,2)+Math.pow(puntoFinal.y-puntoInicial.y, 2));
     
    }
    public void mostrar() {
       System.out.println("la distancia es: "+distancia);
    }
 }
```

Clase punto:

```
 package relacionDeDependencia;

 public class Punto {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Punto(int x0, int y0) {
       x=x0;
       y=y0;
    }
    public void setPunto(int x_actual,int y_actual) {
       x=x_actual;
       y=y_actual;
    }
 }
```

Agradezco de antemano sus respuestas, gracias.

Comment: Quien depende de quien en tu ejemplo?

Comment: la clase Punto es la independiente y la clase distancia la dependiente, es decir, la clase Distancia depende de la clase Punto

Answer (score 1):

Tengo entendido que una relación de dependencia es cuando el objeto  independiente usa como parámetro los objetos de la clase dependiente para que la clase dependiente realice sus operaciones.

```
public double distancia(int pX, int pY) {
    double dis;
    //int dx= this.x - pX;
    int dx= x - pX;
    int dy = this.y - pY;
    dis = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    return dis;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos con un ejemplo un poquitín más visual:

```
class TrianguloRectangulo {

    Punto a;
    Punto b;
    Punto c;
    
    public TrianguloRectangulo( Punto aa, Punto bb, Punto cc ) {
        a = aa;
        b = bb;
        c = cc;
    }
}

class Punto {

    int a;
    int b;

    public Punto( int aa, int bb ) {
        a = aa;
        b = bb;
    }

    public void set( int aa, int bb ) {
        a = aa;
        b = bb;    
    }
}
```

Ahora imaginemos que queremos instanciar un triángulo de 3 x 4 x 5, como el siguiente:

```
a
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
|____\
b     c
```

Podríamos crearlo así:

```
Punto a = new Punto( 10, 10 );
Punto b = new Punto( 10, 14 );
Punto c = new Punto( 13, 14 );
TrianguloRectangulo tri = new TrianguloRectangulo( a, b, c );
```

ahora veamos que pasa si modifico un objeto **Punto**:

```
c.set( 16, 14);
```

automáticamente, mi triángulo pasaría a verse así:

```
a
|\
|  \
|    \
|      \
|________\
b         c
```

al modificar el objeto **Punto** que es un atributo del objeto **TrianguloRectangulo**, estoy modificando a este último.